# how do I install RoR on Linux distros that block sudo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, debian

The Linux distros I've seen use an outdated version of Ruby that is not compatible with Ruby on Rails at all, so I found this set of instructions to install a compatible non-repository version of Ruby as well as RoR on Debian and Ubuntu:

[Debian](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-an-debian-7-0-wheezy-vps-using-rvm)

[Ubuntu](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.10)

The Debian install fails because that method seems absolutely to require sudo. If you install as root you get horrible misconfiguration and no application access as limited user, but you can't install as just a limited user because Debian uses root login and puts up roadblocks to adding sudoers.

I generally like Debian better and would rather run it than Ubuntu, but this issue is forcing me to run Ubuntu instead. So is there a way to get around the sudo blockage in Debian when installing RoR?

Comment: What is your question? You can install rvm as user(for user if you want) and rvm can deliver any ruby version for you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the OS has the tools and libs required to compile build and the gems you'll use, there's no need for `sudo` at all.

Using a version manager is the easiest way to accomplish that. [RVM](https://rvm.io/) is the easiest to use and the one I usually recommend for beginners.

Other version managers I find worth mentioning are [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) (my personal choice), but there's a more comprehensive list [in the RVM docs](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/docs/alt.md).

Comment: My attempt to use the algorithm described in the above link to install Ruby and RoR in Debian 7.7 does rely on RVM, but the install failed at the last step, which is make install, because sudo make install appears to be required to write to the root-privileged directories. Is this a bug in the latest release of Debian?

Comment: RVM shouldn't try to run anything with `sudo` apart from installing missing packages (hence the first sentence on my reply).
Could you pastebin the logs of where this happened?